# Removing tilde from attribute table

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, replace

I am trying to remove the tilde from a few fields in my ArcGIS Pro attribute tables. I was given a few .txt files that I need to join to some landgrid parcel data, but can't do so until I have successfully replaced the "~ ~" from my input tables (see screenshot below).[image: screenshot of attribute table with tildes in fields]
[image: per Vince's suggestion - not sure what about this syntax is wrong.. very new to python and Arcpy i should add.]

I have tried .replace() - and either have the syntax wrong or am using the wrong tool in field calculator.

input:

Field3 = .replace(!Field3!) #field3 is the same as assessment_no highlighted in my attribute table

code block in field calculator:

`.replace('~')`

Wondering if something like .rstrip() may be useful here? I need the numeric and text values between the tildes but can't use them when joining my fields together.

Comment: I suggest you edit the `.txt` files using a text-editor.

Comment: The Calculate Field documentation shows the usage you need to follow. "`.replace`" is not valid, but "`!fieldname!.replace`" is.

Comment: @Erik and manually remove each Tilde?

Comment: @Vince I tried this and assuming my code is still incorrect - added an image for reference.

Comment: Behold the power of `CTRL+H`, aka `search and replace`.

Comment: @Erik eureka!! thank you!! simple fix thank you!!

Comment: You still have a syntax error. The full expression should be `Field3 = !Field3!.replace('~','')`